# MacOSX: which dynamic libraries linked by binary?

Tags: macos, ldd, rpath, otool

I have not been able to figure out why my binary is not loading. It is a dylib loaded by MATLAB (MEX-file), and links to quite a few dylibs in different locations. MATLAB tells me it cannot load the MEX-file, but I cannot figure out which of its dependencies it cannot find.

Does anybody have any suggestions for how to debug something like this?

On Linux, `ldd` is the perfect tool to debug this problem. People keep saying that `otool -L` is the MacOS equivalent to the Linux `ldd`, but this is not true. `ldd` actually looks for the libraries, and tells you which ones can be found, and where they were found. `otool -L` only tells you what libraries are needed to link against. It does not effort to check to see if they are there. It doesn't even tell you where libraries are searched for when they use `@rpath`.

`otool -l` (lowercase L) gives you a dump of the "load commands", there you can see the `LC_RPATH` commands, which establish where `@rpath` libraries are searched for. But these have not been able to explain to me which dependency is not found.

Comment: Also, for inspecting Linux binaries on a macOS, `greadelf` from MacPorts can be used, as well as `nm`: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/418357/43390, also relevant to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23698812/1959808.

Comment: When trying `otool -L` for a Linux executable, an error was raised "object is not a Mach-O file type.".

Comment: @Ioannis: Yes, `otool` is for macOS binaries, not Linux ones. The SO answer you link talks about `otool -L`, which I already mention in the question is not useful in this particular case. `readelf` and `nm` are useful to see what symbols are in the binary, and serve a similar purpose to `otool` with other flags. None of them attempt to replicate the `ldd` functionality.

Comment: Thank you for noting that none of `readelf`, `nm`, and `otool` operate
similarly to how `ldd` does. This comment motivated me to read further,
and the information I collected does not fit in a comment, so I posted it
in an answer to a question that seems closer to what I was searching for: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67818921/1959808

Comment: I arrived to this thread while searching for analysis on macOS of ELF executables (compiled on Linux). My understanding is that this use case is related to the question here, which is phrased about `dylib`, so Mach-O analysis on macOS, and what for Mach-O on macOS is the closest thing to `ldd` for ELF on Linux. My purpose for commenting was informational, to provide pointers for others that might find this thread while searching for ELF analysis on macOS.

Comment: I thought I was using macOS's `otool`, but was actually using the `otool` that is part of MacPorts package the `cctools` (installed as `/opt/local/bin/otool`). Both variants raise an error when given an ELF file, with tiny differences in the error message: `/opt/local/bin/otool -L file_name` says "llvm-objdump: error: file_name': object is not a Mach-O file type.", whereas `/usr/bin/otool -L` says: "llvm-objdump: 'file_name': Object is not a Mach-O file type.".

Comment: My comment about `otool` was intended for the ELF case only. If `otool` supported ELF files, it might have sufficed for what I was trying to confirm (I was looking for some specific versioned symbols). I did not intend to suggest that `otool` is equivalent to `ldd`. As you have noted, in general, `otool` does not perform the kind of analysis that `ldd` does.

Comment: Above, I linked to the SO answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23698812/1959808 with the purpose of linking the two threads.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Try setting these environment variables before running matlab:

```
export DYLD_PRINT_LIBRARIES=1
export DYLD_PRINT_LIBRARIES_POST_LAUNCH=1
export DYLD_PRINT_RPATHS=1
```

Run `man dyld` for more possibilities.

You can also set the variables for just the matlab command like this:

```
DYLD_PRINT_LIBRARIES=1 DYLD_PRINT_LIBRARIES_POST_LAUNCH=1 DYLD_PRINT_RPATHS=1 matlab
```

Comment: This is excellent, thank you so much! Matlab has a boot script that seems to not pass on environment variables to the executable, so I added these variables to the script. I also used `DYLD_PRINT_TO_FILE`.

Answer (score 12):

Rob Mayoff's answer is a great solution when working with executables. If you find you need to check the runtime dependencies of a dylib, the following script `my-ldd` may be useful.

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash 

while getopts "r" OPTION; do
  case $OPTION in   
    r) export DYLD_PRINT_RPATHS=1;;
  esac
done
shift $((OPTIND-1))

cp `which true` .
DYLD_PRINT_LIBRARIES=1 \
DYLD_PRINT_LIBRARIES_POST_LAUNCH=1 \
DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES=$1 \
./true
rm ./true
```

where a the script may be invoked as

```
my-ldd ./foo.dylib
```

or (with rpath attempts echo'd)

```
my-ldd -r ./foo.dylib
```

Comment: Nice! What is the reason this needs a local copy of the `true` binary? I tried running `/usr/bin/true` in this way and it doesn't work.

Comment: I encountered the same issue. It's an enhanced security measure put in place by Apple. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48478771/2471708) link for more discussion

Comment: On my MacOS version 22.5.0 it does not work with `/usr/bin/true` nor with other pre-installed binaries. Yet I compiled my own trivial `true` command, this way it works also without copying the binary.

Answer (score 1):

Your `my-ldd` script was a great idea!

I also encountered some issues with the apple [SIP](https://apple.co/3sDkQZJ) limitation, plus I also found a bit tricky to deal with multiple architecture.

So I extended it to detect the dylib architecture and I workarounded the SIP by creating an simple executable on the spot (credit to [the thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39623829) of @okutane)

The result is at: https://github.com/tetractius/ldd-apple/blob/main/ldd-apple.sh