# ‘ldd -r’ equivalent on macOS

Tags: macos, ldd, nm, otool

I am trying to make my software available on macOS, and in my toolchain I use the `ldd -r MyModel.so` command to verify that everything went well, but I can’t really find an equivalent command on macOS with the same behavior.

`otool` and `nm` seem to be the two directions to go, but which of their options provide the behavior of `ldd -r`? Is there any other tool that can be used for this purpose?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

`ldd` uses `ld` to load executable files, and recursively loads
dynamically-linked libraries. So using `ldd` requires being on the target system
(e.g., Linux). Thus, `ldd` cannot be used for ELF files on macOS.

Assuming that the question is about analyzing Mach-O files on macOS, I do not know of any tool that works for Mach-O files as `ldd` does for ELF files.
Both `otool` and `nm` perform a static analysis.

A possibility is:

```bash
otool -L /usr/bin/true
```

Relevant:

- [MacOSX: which dynamic libraries linked by binary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45464584/macosx-which-dynamic-libraries-linked-by-binary)
- [Inspect and get binary from ELF file on MAC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57924712/inspect-and-get-binary-from-elf-file-on-mac)